# Display query results in controller as array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and want to create restfull api, but I amstuck in displaying results of query at inside of array.

This is standart code if without query database:

```
 $users = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Guy', 'email' => 'example1@example.com'),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Person Face', 'email' => 'example2@example.com'),
        3 => array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Scotty', 'email' => 'example3@example.com', 'fact' => array('hobbies' => array('fartings', 'bikes'))),
    );
```

And how to display all results from database at inside of array like that?

Thank you.

Comment: what?.. so you have an array with table parameters(from what it seems), and you want to display results from database?... what do you mean exactly? Do you want to query the database so that your results are in that structure? Please be more clear

Answer (score -1):

```
   $this->load->model( 'query'); 
   $data_news = $this->query->getall();
   $this->response($data_news);
```

Comment: explain what this does. You need to provide details with your code